# How to make a copy of a reference type

Tags: c#, immutability, reference-type

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cloning objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c)

I have a class with properties and some of them are reference types (instances of other classes) themselves (`CookieContainer`).

I want to have a exact copy of this class so any change to previous version would not affect this new instance.

Is there a general solution for this kind of problems or I should do it manually ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to deep copy the object to another object. There are many approaches to this but serializing one object and deserializing that data into another object is a very quick trick to achieve this. See it here: [How do you do a deep copy of an object in .NET (C# specifically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)

Answer (score -1):

Decide how deep you want your copy and implement the ICloneable interface and Clone method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable