# How to implement ICollection.CopyTo method?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a class that implements `ICollection<T>` and `ICollection` interfaces.

MSDN says these are a bit different. [`ICollection<T>.CopyTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0efx51xw.aspx) takes a `T[]` argument, whereas [`ICollection.CopyTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.copyto.aspx) takes a `System.Array` argument. There is also a difference between exceptions thrown.

Here is my implementation of the generic method (I believe it's fully functional):

```
void ICollection<PlcParameter>.CopyTo(PlcParameter[] array, int arrayIndex)
{
    if (array == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    if (arrayIndex < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("arrayIndex");
    if (array.Length - arrayIndex < Count)
        throw new ArgumentException("Not enough elements after arrayIndex in the destination array.");

    for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
        array[i + arrayIndex] = this[i];
}
```

However, the non-generic version of the method is confusing me a bit. First, **how do I check for the following exception condition**?

> The type of the source ICollection cannot be cast automatically to the type of the destination array.

Second, **is there a way to leverage the existing generic implementation** to reduce code duplication?

Here is my work-in-progress implementation:

```
void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
{
    if (array == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    if (index < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("arrayIndex");
    if (array.Rank > 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("array is multidimensional.");
    if (array.Length - index < Count)
        throw new ArgumentException("Not enough elements after index in the destination array.");

    for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
        array.SetValue(this[i], i + index);
}
```

Comment: Well `SetValue` will definitely throw a cast exception for you.

Comment: Can you implement your class by deriving from [`CollectionBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.collectionbase_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to save work? It implements `CopyTo()` for you.

Comment: have a look to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843958/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-reference-type

Comment: @juharr catching the `CastException` to throw the `ArgumentException` is needless expense though.

Comment: On second thoughts, `CollectionBase` is ancient and predates generics, so perhaps that's not a good idea...

Comment: There is Collection<T> instead that is generic and basically wraps a List<T> with extension points. Its specifically for writing custom generic collections.

Comment: @MatthewWatson So is ICollection but not that I can escape it here. :) CollectionBase wouldn't suit me because the collection needs to be read-only. But I wasn't aware of ReadOnlyCollectionBase until now so I'm looking into it. As you can see, not an expert here.

Comment: @HansPassant Don't I need to be able to cast the class I'm writing into an Array for that? And wouldn't that step potentially add bugs as well?

Comment: @HansPassant that's assuming the underlying implementation is an array, which it might not be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've already done most of the work in implementing `ICollection<T>.CopyTo`.

There are four possibilities for `ICollection.CopyTo`:

1. It will work the same as `ICollection<T>`.
2. It will fail for a reason `ICollection<T>` would have failed.
3. It will fail because of rank-mismatch.
4. It will fail because of type mismatch.

We can handle the first two by calling into `ICollection<T>.CopyTo`.

In each of these cases `array as PlcParameter[]` will give us a reference to the array, strongly typed.

In each of the latter cases, it won't.

We do want to catch `array == null` separately though:

```
void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
{
  if (array == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
  PlcParameter[] ppArray = array as PlcParameter[];
  if (ppArray == null)
    throw new ArgumentException();
  ((ICollection<PlcParameter>)this).CopyTo(ppArray, index);
}
```

If you really wanted you could test `array.Rank == 1` in the case of `ppArray` being null, and change the error message accordingly.

(BTW, why are you explicitly implementing `ICollection<PlcParameter>.CopyTo`? it's likely enough to be useful to be work implementing explicitly, so people don't have to cast to all it.)

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems like the perfect solution. I didn't think of casting to `T[]` for some reason. I'll also take your advice about not implementing explicitly.

Comment: If you do that then you can change the rather ugly `((ICollection<PlcParameter>)this).CopyTo(ppArray, index)` to just `CopyTo(ppArray, index)`.

Answer (score 3):

In the non-generic `CopyTo` the following cases can happen:

- Types actually match: call the generic version
- The array is `object[]`: Handle this one as well, especially if `T` is a reference type since in this case `T[]` can be cast to `object[]`
- If your collection is a dictionary, you can handle the `KeyValuePair[]` and `DictionaryEntry[]` arrays as well

So in a general case you should use the following implementation:

```
void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
{
    if (array != null && array.Rank != 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("Only single dimensional arrays are supported for the requested action.", "array");

    // 1. call the generic version
    T[] typedArray = array as T[];
    if (typedArray != null)
    {
        CopyTo(typedArray, index);
        return;
    }

    // 2. object[]
    object[] objectArray = array as object[];
    if (objectArray != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            objectArray[index++] = GetElementAt(i);
        }
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("Target array type is not compatible with the type of items in the collection.");
}
```